# Port Forwarding Apache Web Server

Tags: apache-http-server, port, web, forwarding

I am trying to setup my local pc to be visible to the WWW. I already use apache/mysql on my local pc - day to day but now i want to make it visible online. My real goal isn't to run a website but just to set it up so i can give my ip to my clients so they can check the progress of the project i'm working for them. It would really ease things up for me.

After quite some stuggle, dealing with Port Forwarding i can see the port i want being forwarded by checking @ http://canyouseeme.org/

But even though it shows the port is forwarded, i still cannot manage to get the page loaded it just times-out (saying the request is taking too long).

At first, i thought maybe the ISP might be blocking the port i needed but that doesn't seem to be the case to me, i tried using multiple ports by changing the Listen Port in my httpd.conf file and also forwarding it through my Router's UI.

I tried disabling Windows Firewall and Router Filewall too but it didn't help at all :(
I have a Dynamic IP so it changes everytime my router restarts.

I'm not sure what i could be doing wrong, but for some reason it seems like something is blocking my pc from receiving request? I'm using Windows 7.

**Edit:-
I forgot to mention my Router Model is **ZXDSL 831II - Its a ZTE router****

---

### **My IPCONFIG /ALL Response is all below:**

Windows IP Configuration

```
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : admin-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1C-C0-C5-51-8B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a44e:201f:9e34:1a53%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234888384
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-0C-7E-E9-00-1C-C0-C5-51-8B

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 119.159.255.37
                                       203.99.163.240
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E2181546-0396-4C0E-ADBD-BB4739320ED1}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:149b:2c93:8864:8d3d(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::149b:2c93:8864:8d3d%11(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

---

**Here is my NETSTAT Response:**

### It shows the server is listening to the port i am using 55222 for apache:

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing a forwarded port from inside the network doesn't always work and depends greatly on the router. [This link](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/loopback_connections.html) gives an explanation of the problem and a few suggested fixes. Mostly either "don't do it" or "allowing 'loop back' connections" in your router config.

In the case of home routers, I have been able to allow this after finding a hidden setting somewhere but it's manufacturer specific.

You might want to check your router's documentation (or provide its identity here) to see if this setting exists for it. Different people call it different things but it often has '*loop*' in the name.

Comment: @PriceChild: Sorry i forgot to mention my Router Model is **ZXDSL 831II**

Comment: I tried everything my noobish mind could comprehend, i've been trying to get this to work for about 2-3 years but everytime i gave up in-between, this is the first time i came to the point that it finally started showing some results (which being that it started showing the port as opened) lol - I'm not that good with Networking Stuff. Do you have any idea what that secret setting for my router would be?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a manual but i've looked at a similar router [here](http://screenshots.portforward.com/ZTE/ZXDSL-831CII/index.htm) and haven't found the option you require. I'm afraid the answer may just be "its not possible with your router".

Comment: And just to clarify... if you test this from outside your network, it 'should' work if you've set it up properly. I just don't think it will work when testing from inside your network.

Comment: [This link](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/loopback_connections.html) describes the problem, I'm not making it up! :-)

Comment: Perhaps try temporarily disabling the router's firewall and see if that fixes it? See [here](http://screenshots.portforward.com/ZTE/ZXDSL-831CII/Advanced_Firewall.htm)

Comment: @PriceChild: thanks for digging into this, i'm certain i know i've seen people some where claiming they have successfully setuped an online server using the same router as i have, i know port-forwarding is possible and works because my uTorrent is forwarding just fine and working great. and I have a already tried disabling the windows firewall and also the router's firewall together, but no good results from that, also tried using DMZ too.

Comment: I forwarded my ports using the following guide:
http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/ZXDSL831v2 which is the mode i have.

Comment: Just as a test, i tried forwarding counter strike ports to see if the server comes online and it isn't doing this either, i am pretty sure i knew someone who did this with his router, which was the same as mine and i've sparred with him on his server for a while :)

Comment: Don't expect it to. The whole point is that you can't access the forwarded port from within your home network. Your friend should be able to access your server though.

Comment: You're Awesome :) and right :) I asked a friend to check if he can access my server and he was able to access it just fine :) isn't there any way i can access it myself using the public ip? :(

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but in my system32/drivers/etc file i have manually defined sometime ago the following: 127.0.0.1 localhost (or maybe i think i just uncommented it) :) but commenting it back doesn't help :)

Comment: No, its a 'feature'/'bug' of your router. It just doesn't allow it and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to make it work. What you've seen in your hosts file is standard.

Comment: dang :( so if got a new router, it would work for me too? btw that that line in hosts file it used to be uncommented in previous versions of windows (i know it was in XP) but not sure about Vista and in Windows 7 it surely was either commented or missing can't remember but it was either of it, i went crazy because of that when i switched to Windows 7 because apache or maybe mysql or both were behaving oddly because of that line missing.

Comment: Depends on the router.

Answer (score 0):

**I found 2 solutions to my above problem:**

1). I can access my own IP using a web-based proxy service like kProxy.com or something similar to that. [tested]

2). It might also be possible to access by just changing my DNS to a third-party DNS something like Google Public DNS or OpenDNS, though i haven't tried this. [untested]

If someone knows or has tested the second solution, please do post.